# Why do my droplist items occupy so much space in IE8?

Tags: html, css

In my dropdown so many items are loading. In Mozilla it's coming out good, but in IE8 it's occupying so much space for that I applied the below css like this. But it's not affecting that style.

```
 <span id="filterByApplication"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByApplicationName", new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedApplication.Name), "ALL", new { @class = "drop-menu" })%></span>

 .drop-menu 
   {
    max-height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
   /* border: 1px solid #f6f0e4;*/
}
  .drop-menu li
  {
      position:relative;
  }
```

Please tell me how to avoid more space of dropdown items in IE browsers?

Comment: Could be the box-model; is your document in Standards Mode? Are you using any CSS Reset stylesheets? What happens if you add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to the top of your CSS file? Can you give us a screenshot of the layout panel for this element in your F12 Developer Tools, compared to the layout in your Chrome Developer Tools? Just a few things to help the content of your question.

Comment: @JonathanSampson If you only use `box-sizing`, you introduce browser incompatibilities. Since the OP notes that it looks good in Mozilla, you should at least include the `-moz-` version of the property. (Firefox doesn't use the non-prefixed version yet.)

Comment: @user3106578 Stupid question, but are you sure that the CSS matches the HTML? Does the `Html.DropDownList` create a list? I thought it created a `select` control...

Comment: @Lister please tell me clearly answer for my question.i am not getting.

Comment: Can u provide the screenshot as Jonathan asked?

Comment: @user3106578 We need more information. Put your code in a demo and store it on http://jsfiddle.net. And please disregard comments like "IE sucks big time," as these don't reflect reality. The fact is that from IE8 and up, well-written code would rarely have any issues.